# Executing a stored procedure from the fields list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HO_GetListOfLeaguesPerLocation]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT LeagueID, (EXEC dbo.HO_GetLeagueNumOfMatches LeagueID)
    FROM Games
END
```

I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the Keyword EXEC.

When I run this query alone, without anything else, it goes well.

I also tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LeagueID, dbo.HO_GetLeagueNumOfMatches(LeagueID)
```

AND:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LeagueID, SELECT * FROM dbo.HO_GetLeagueNumOfMatches(LeagueID)
```

AND:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LeagueID, SELECT dbo.HO_GetLeagueNumOfMatches(LeagueID)
```

None worked.

Any idea how should I run this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a (scalar) function for this. Stored procedures cannot be used here.

(You can not use APPLY with a stored procedure.)